# LDAP module + Windows AD

Tags: authentication-authorization

I have a large AD setup which has not been configured in the ideal fashion, the base DN:

```
dc=davinci,dc=mydomain,dc=local
```

Now the existing structure of our AD looks something like:

```
@ 1122 Logan
  Accounting
  Aquarius
    Alejandro
    Mike 
    Justin 
  Aerospace
  Distribution
  Engineering
@ 2150 Logan
  Uniflyte
@ 1480 Church
```

Trying to test the authentication of the user Alejandro (old network guy was being funny when he gave me a user name).

Here is my Server Property Dump:

**Server Properties:**

```
sid = Davinci
numeric_sid = 1
name = Employees
status = 1
ldap_type = ad
address = davinci
port = 389
tls = 0
followrefs = 0
bind_method = 2
basedn = Array ( [0] => dc=davinci,dc=cadorath,dc=local )
binddn =
user_dn_expression = cn=%username,%basedn
user_attr = samaccountname
account_name_attr =
mail_attr =
mail_template =
picture_attr =
unique_persistent_attr =
unique_persistent_attr_binary = 0
ldap_to_drupal_user =
testing_drupal_username = Alejandro
testing_drupal_user_dn = cn=Alejandro,ou=@ 1122 Logan,dc=davinci,dc=mydomain,dc=local
grp_unused = 0
grp_object_cat =
grp_nested = 0
grp_user_memb_attr_exists = 0
grp_user_memb_attr =
grp_memb_attr =
grp_memb_attr_match_user_attr =
grp_derive_from_dn = 0
grp_derive_from_dn_attr =
grp_test_grp_dn =
grp_test_grp_dn_writeable =
search_pagination = 0
search_page_size = 1000
```

I enter in my password for non-anonymous search (Windows login password)...

**Testing Drupal DN:**

> cn=Alejandro,ou=@ 1122 Logan,dc=davinci-1,dc=cadorath,dc=local

Drupal logs report:

```
LDAP bind failure for user userdn=, pass=XXX.
```

Where does the userdn get constructed???

I still cannot login to drupal with Windows login details...D7 is running in the same domain as Davinci so I assume I missing something in the syntax of connection string???

Comment: Which version of the ldap module are you using?  This is working for me similar to the answer from tenken.

Answer (score 0):

The ldap config page for users and fields has a *user_dn* entry you can set.

Comment: I visit: admin/config/people/accounts/fields and see an "ldap_user_current_dn" field but its hidden and locked for modification? How does this supposed to work?

Comment: hmmm, on my setup(s) its usually not inactive. It lets you set the DN needed for some LDAP configurations. On a Windows LDAP box (I never got to fully work), I was using the following based on sysadmins request `cn=%username@YOURDOMAIN.FOO,%basedn`